# Observable.Where with async predicate

Tags: c#, async-await, system.reactive

Is there a convenient way to use an async function as the predicate of a `Where` operator on an observable?

For example, if I have a nice tidy but possibly long-running function defined like this:

```
Task<int> Rank(object item);
```

Is there a trick to passing it to `Where` and maintaining the asynchronous execution? As in:

```
myObservable.Where(async item => (await Rank(item)) > 5)
```

In the past, when I've needed to do this, I've resorted to using `SelectMany` and projecting those results into a new type along with the original value and then doing the filtering based on that.

```
myObservable.SelectMany(async item => new 
  {
    ShouldInclude = (await Rank(item)) > 5,
    Item = item
  })
  .Where(o => o.ShouldInclude)
  .Select(o => o.Item);
```

I think that's terribly unreadable, though and I feel like there must be a cleaner way.

Comment: Do you want items to enter the result stream at the time their `Rank` completed, or would they maintain their original order?

Comment: I'd be interested in both, but let's say for this case order isn't a concern.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I think that's terribly unreadable

Yes, but you can fix that by encapsulating it into a helper method. If you call it `Where`, you will get exactly the syntax you wanted:

```
public static IObservable<T> Where<T>(
    this IObservable<T> source, Func<T, Task<bool>> predicate)
{
    return source.SelectMany(async item => new 
        {
            ShouldInclude = await predicate(item),
            Item = item
        })
        .Where(x => x.ShouldInclude)
        .Select(x => x.Item);
}
```

Comment: +1. This is probably the most straightforward solution.

Comment: That's actually great. I can't believe that hadn't occurred to me before.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you could use something like this:

```
public static IObservable<T> Where<T>(
    this IObservable<T> source, Func<T, Task<bool>> predicate)
{
    return source.SelectMany(item => 
        predicate(item).ToObservable()
            .Select(include => include ? Observable.Return(item) : Observable.Empty<T>())
        );
}
```

Which is basically how `Where` works, if you definited it in terms of SelectMany`:

```
public static IObservable<T> Where<T>(
    this IObservable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    return source.SelectMany(item => predicate(item) ? Observable.Return(item) : Observable.Empty<T>());
}
```

Actually though, @svick's answer has less closures. :)

Comment: Why are you using `Map()` instead of the more common name (at least in C#) `Select()`?

Comment: `map` is the standard function programming term. `Select` is a legacy term left over from the original LINQ to SQL implementation. `Map` doesn't exist in the .NET version of Rx, as far as I know, but does exist in RxJS. Basically, I'm just used to writing `map` and not `Select`.

Comment: Actually, [`Map()` does exist](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/blob/master/Rx.NET/Source/System.Reactive.Observable.Aliases/Observable.Aliases.cs#L41) in the `System.Reactive.Observable.Aliases` namespace.

Comment: Ahh, in that case I'll probably start using it in .NET to be consistent with the rest of the world. :)